Received Facebook Graph API Upgrade Reminder but API Upgrade Tool show nothing to upgrade
I received FB email saying

Your app is currently accessing Graph API v13.0 which will reach the end of its 2-year lifetime on 28 May, 2024. We estimate 7 endpoints that App calls will be impacted by this change and may stop working after the automatic upgrade push.

However, when I go to the API Upgrade Tool, it said

Your app has no changes for the methods you selected between v13.0 and v19.0

Does it mean I don't need to do anything, e.g. upgrade my FB client library?

These warnings are issued automatically when there are upgrades, based on your API calls.
You just need to use the API version in your URL: https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/....
You use version flag to your API calls or just wait until v13.0 is deprecated and your app will be upgraded to v19.0 automatically.
You might also start getting service errors after 28 May. You can use the "upgrade API calls" setting to test this before that happens.
You can also change in the Facebook developer console under (settings/advanced) what Graph API version you want to use.
However, you might want to test what happens before the upgrade as your app might stop working.
